# WKWebView crash: "Requestor is not a platform binary"

Tags: ios, crash, ios9, wkwebview

I have a `UIPageViewController` that loads a `UIViewController` which in turn contains a `WKWebView`. The app lets me swipe indefinitely. After about 30 or so swipes, the app dies without any crash log. The memory was constant at about 15 MB, so it didn't seem to be a memory issue.

I did, however, find this in the device log:

```
Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 154: Requestor is not a platform binary
```

This was on iOS 9.0.1 on an iPad mini 1. The only thing I found about it is this: http://prod.lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2015/Jul/msg00461.html (I'm not using an internal web server, though).

Any thoughts as to what might cause this or how to fix it?

Comment: Ever find a fix for this?

Comment: @RichmondWatkins Nope. I looked very much like an iOS bug and it seems as if it was fixed in a later iOS 9 release.